# Sides of a triangle (square roots)?

Tags: geometry, number-theory

This is the exercise: Let $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Prove that the following propositions are equivalents:

1. $a,b,c$ are sides of a triangle.
2. $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c}$ are sides of an acute triangle.

I'd really appreciate your help in this exercise. :)

Comment: If the triangle $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c}$ is a right triangle, by the pythagorean theorem $a+b=c$, thus $abc$ cannot be a triangle.  I suspect you can apply the Law of Cosines the same way to show the result for an obtuse triangle.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c}$ be the sides of a non-acute triangle.  There is some angle $\theta$ in the triangle of at least 90 degrees.  Without loss of generality let it be opposite the side of length $\sqrt{c}$.  Then we have, from the Law of Cosines, $c=a+b-2\sqrt{ab}\cos\theta$.  We know $\cos\theta\le 0$.  Hence $c\ge a+b$, implying $a,b,c$ cannot be a triangle.

Comment: That was great....+1

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Suppose that $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle. Without loss of generality we may assume that $c\ge a$ and $c\ge b$.

Then $a,b,c$ are the sides of a triangle if and only if $a+b\ge c$.

First we show that $\sqrt{a},\sqrt{b},\sqrt{c}$ are the sides of a triangle. We need to show that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\gt \sqrt{c}$. This is easy, for if $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}\le \sqrt{c}$ then, squaring, we obtain $a+2\sqrt{ab}+b\le c$, which implies that $a+b\lt c$.

Note that $a+b\gt c$  implies that $(\sqrt{a})^2+(\sqrt{b})^2 \gt (\sqrt{c})^2$. And this is precisely the condition for the largest angle of the triangle with sides $\sqrt{a}$, $\sqrt{b}$, $\sqrt{c}$ to be less than a right angle. For details, use the Cosine Law.

We leave the proof in the other direction to you.